# CSS3/ Infinite vertical scrolling carousel with variable width child elements

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions, carousel

Piggybacking off [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27455064/infinite-vertical-scroll-div-element) and [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27455064/infinite-vertical-scroll-div-element/28559988#28559988) I have something that needs more work. I have a similar scrolling need, but with child divs and not list elements, and importantly the divs contain images that are all the same width but variable height. Using the animate/scrolltop I cannot get smooth scrolling.

Essentially, I want behavior like in this [codepen](http://jsfiddle.net/p6wkm4q8/) but with variable height, like in [this codepen](http://jsfiddle.net/eox8dfka/) (which isn't working), because the height of the child element doesn't allow the animate scrollTop to accurately compute:

```
setInterval(function(){
 var first_height = $('#list').find('div:first').height(); $('#list').stop().animate({scrollTop:first_height},2650,'linear',function(){
    $(this).scrollTop(0).find('div:last').after($('div:first', this));
  });
}, 2700);
```

Can anyone offer any tips?

EDIT: almost there with [this pen based on the answer below](https://jsfiddle.net/8ozx09ca/). I get "snapping to grid" functionality instead of smooth scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have set **a fixed height** in your CSS but you didn't include the **paddings** and **margins** measurement into your total **height** of the div you want to set scrollTop animation.

[image]

In order to achieve precise measurement of every elements in the container, we need to get the actual paddings and margins of the element using **jQuery.css()**.

> **TAKE NOTE**

CSS shorthand properties are not supported by the **jQuery.css()** function. So we need to define everything in the traditional way (LMAO).

Use of **parseInt()** is necessary as the results of **jQuery** functions are returned as **characters/string**, making it concatenate the two results instead of adding them.

> Example: parseInt($('#list').find('div:first').css('padding-top')) + parseInt($('#list').find('div:first').css('padding-bottom'));
>
> will result in **[10 + 10 = 20]**
>
> and $('#list').find('div:first').css('padding-top') + $('#list').find('div:first').css('padding-bottom');
>
> will result in **['10' + '10' = '1010']**

```js
var interval = 1000;
setInterval(function() {
var first_height = $('#list').find('div:first').height();
var paddings = parseInt($('#list').find('div:first').css('padding-top')) + parseInt($('#list').find('div:first').css('padding-bottom'));
var margins = parseInt($('#list').find('div:first').css('margin-top')) + parseInt($('#list').find('div:first').css('margin-bottom'));
var animation = interval - paddings - margins;
  $('#list').stop().animate({
    scrollTop: first_height + paddings + margins
  }, animation, 'linear', function() {
    $(this).scrollTop(0).find('div:last').after($('div:first', this));
  });
}, interval);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#list {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
}

#list div {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="list">
  <div style="height: 30px;">Item 1</div>
  <div style="height: 50px;">Item 2</div>
  <div style="height: 30px;">Item 3</div>
  <div style="height: 50px;">Item 4</div>
  <div style="height: 30px;">Item 5</div>
  <div style="height: 50px;">Item 6</div>
  <div style="height: 30px;">Item 7</div>
  <div style="height: 50px;">Item 8</div>
  <div style="height: 30px;">Item 9</div>
  <div style="height: 50px;">Item 10</div>
</div>
```

> Source: [jQuery API | .css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/), [jQuery API | .animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Comment: Super helpful, almost there!! I updated this snippet - https://jsfiddle.net/8ozx09ca/ (also in my original answer) but there's still a "hiccup" in the scrolling, how do I make it super smooth - I tried playing with the setInterval value and the animate and it kept snapping the top of each item to the top.. I want a real smooth scrolling. Thank you.

Comment: Also, if I wanted to switch the direction, would it be as straightforward as a negative scrollTop of the same value or something else? Thanks again.

Comment: Updated the answer. However, transitions are smooth but animations are not equal. You may need more complex conditions in order to achieve even transitions on different HTML Element dimensions.